# How to detect the movement of a phone while driving?

Tags: java, android, ios, accelerometer, motion

We need to track the phone is in the drive mode without using gps.
We have tried with accelerometer, but it happen only when the phone is in motion.

Comment: How can i track using eyes?

Comment: Physics tells us you can't. Unaccelearated motion cannot be detected unless you look at some outside reference.

Comment: There a drive mode in Motorola phones. Can u tell the logic behind these drive mode without the help of GPS?

Comment: Please explain what 'drive mode' means to You ?

Comment: How do you know they're not using GPS?

Comment: I have tried it without turn on GPS. When i am driving automatically shows the Drive mode notification .

Comment: So I have developed using accelerometer, but everytime the x,y, z values are changing.

Comment: CoreMotion on iOS reports drive motion when it detects you are driving.  When you stop, say at traffic lights, then it will report that you aren't driving, because you aren't.  Your app would have to see if the next reported motion type is walking or driving to work out what is happening.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can u suggest any coding example?

Comment: The relevant class on iOS is documented here - https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Significant Motion Sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-significant)
The significant motion sensor triggers an event each time significant motion is detected and then it disables itself. A significant motion is a motion that might lead to a change in the user's location; for example walking, biking, or sitting in a moving car.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private TriggerEventListener mTriggerEventListener;

mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);

mTriggerEventListener = new TriggerEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTrigger(TriggerEvent event) {
        // Do work
    }
};

mSensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(mTriggerEventListener, mSensor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

And this:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @Paulw11 i appreciate  your view but you have not added any code when asking question , so i can't suggest anything because i don't know where is exactly problem you have.

Comment: I am not asking a question.  I am pointing out that answers on Stack Overflow should be relatively self-contained.  You shouldn't simply put a couple of links and say "here you go".

Comment: I have red these links, but problem is i can't detect the phone is moving without any distraction in the position.